# Changed incoming props not rerendering react-sortable-hoc list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-sortable-hoc

I'm currently trying to add react-sortable-hoc to a list component and I'm running into a number of bugs when I change the incoming list of items via props. For example: if I add an item to the array, and I check the incoming props for the list, the props in the sortable component are changing (I see the new item in the list component props), but I can't get the component to re-render. I've tried shouldComponentUpdate, getDerivedStateFromProps, using PureComponent instead of Component, forceUpdate, hookifying the whole thing and setting up a useEffect for any change in props, nothing is causing a rerender and I know that the new list is getting to the component.

Is anyone else having this same problem or has anyone found a way around it?

here's how I'm setting props/state, and how I know the props are changing:

```js
class MobileListItems extends Component {

  state = {
    items: this.props.listItems,
  }

.
.
.

  render() {

    console.log('this.props.listItems', this.props.listItems)
    console.log('this.state.items', this.state.items)
```

after I sort a few things, and try to add another item, `this.props.listItems` is incremented by 1, but no rerender no matter which method above I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOOPSIE DAISY! Don't copy your props into state, y'all. Don't be like me!

removing state management and turning this into a function fixed all the bugs I was encountering.